# Run length encoding for java program

Tags: java, string, algorithm, encoding

```
public static String compress(String original) {
    int count = 1;
    char currentChar = original.charAt(0);
    String newString = "";

    for (int x = 1; x < original.length(); x++) {
        if (currentChar == original.charAt(x)) {
            count++;
        } else {
            if (count == 1) {
                newString += Character.toString(currentChar);
            } else {
                newString += Integer.toString(count) + Character.toString(currentChar);
            }
            count = 1;
        }
        currentChar = original.charAt(x);
    }
    return newString;
}
```

My code above is supposed to encode a string using RLE, so if a string is `sssWWwRttty` the program should return `3s2WwR3ty`. The problem I'm running into is that the return value ignores the last character in the string. For example, if the argument for the compress method was `sssWWwRttty` the return value would be `3s2WwR3t` or if the agument was `qwwwEErtttyyyyy` the return value would be `q3w2Er3t`. Does anyone see where I could be missing something for it to be excluding that portion of the string?

Comment: Aside: You must be fairly sure your input doesn’t contain digits? Or the RLE would be anbiguous. You probably ought to check.

Comment: For this program I was assuming there would be no digit inputs, but thank you. I'll take that into account.

Comment: Please check my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67393048/4515438

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never add `currentChar` in the last run of your loop to `newString`.

For performance I highly recommend to build your result in a `StringBuilder` instead of appending to a `String`. Appending to a `String` always creates a new String-Object which costs time and leads to a lot of object creation.