# Kotlin: Run length encoding

Tags: kotlin, stringindexoutofbounds

The program works, however, I still get a logical error: the final letter doesn't run through. For example, when I enter aaaabbbbccccdddd the output I get is a4b4c4 but there is no d4.

```
fun main () {

    val strUser = readLine()!!.toLowerCase()
    val iLength = strUser!!.length
    var iMatch : Int = 0
    var chrMatch : Char = strUser[0]

    for (i in 0..iLength) {

        if (strUser[i] == chrMatch) {

            iMatch += 1
        }else {
            print("$chrMatch$iMatch")
            chrMatch = strUser[i]
            iMatch = 1

        }


    }


}
```

Comment: When you iterate something, you need to go up to one less than its size or length, because the counting begins at zero. In this case, you could eliminate the `iLength` variable altogether and use `for (i in strUser.indices)`. Or more simply, you could use something like `for (chr in strUser)` and use `chr` in place of `strUser[i]`.

Comment: "this error thrown" - what error do you get?

Comment: its a loigcal error @halfer for example when i enter aaaabbbbccccdddd the output i get is a4b4c4 but there is no d4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strUser` contains chars by indexes from `0` to `iLength - 1` so you have to write `for (i in 0 until iLength)` instead of `for (i in 0..iLength)`

But Tenfour04 is completely right, you can just iterate `strUser` without indexes:

```
fun main() {
    val strUser = readLine()!!.toLowerCase()
    var iMatch: Int = 0
    var chrMatch: Char = strUser[0]

    for (char in strUser) {
        if (char == chrMatch) {
            iMatch += 1
        } else {
            print("$chrMatch$iMatch")
            chrMatch = char
            iMatch = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: strUser contains chars by indexes from 0 to iLength - 1.

Comment: @forpas thanks for noticing! I meant it but mistyped :)

Answer (score 3):

There are many solutions, but the best is `RegExp`

```
fun encode(input: String): String =
    input.replace(Regex("(.)\\1*")) {
        String.format("%d%s", it.value.length, it.groupValues[1])
    }
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/8DC57b/1)

**Test result**

```
println(encode("aaaabbbbccccdddd")) // 4a4b4c4d
```

Answer (score 0):

fun main () {

```
val strUser = readLine()!!.toLowerCase()
var iMatch : Int = 0
var chrMatch : Char = strUser[0]

for (char in strUser+1) {

    if (char == chrMatch) {

        iMatch += 1
    }else {
        print("$chrMatch$iMatch")
        chrMatch = char
        iMatch = 1

    }


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
fun runLengthEncoding(inputString: String): String {
        val n=inputString.length
        var i : Int =0
        var result : String =""
        while(i<n){
            var count =1
            while(i<n-1 && inputString[i] == inputString[i+1]){
                count ++
                i++
            }

            result=result.toString()+count.toString()+inputString[i].toString()
            i++
        }
        return result
    }
```